# How to get an hyperlink for a part of a string - in a navbar "li"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to display at a "li" in a navbar a string (e.g. 'Welcome username') while only 'username' is a hyperlink:
e.g.

```
    <li>Welcome <a href="/users/username">username</a></li>
```

"Welcome [username](http://example.com/users/username)" <- like this.

When doing this in a navbar,  I get the string 'Welcome username' splited in two lines

Please see the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ywsY/7/show

SOLVED: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9ywsY/12/show

Comment: can you rephrase your topic please?

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav li a { display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Much better! but the words are showed  separated :-( .Any solution for this? Please see the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ywsY/11/show/

Comment: SOLVED: http://jsfiddle.net/9ywsY/12/  `.nav li a { display: inline-block;
margin-left: -8px; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav > li > a {
    display: inline;
}
```

Inline block doesn't work well on all browsers :)

Alternatively if you really want it to be a block, you could just put all the text inside the anchor tag

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="/users/username">Welcome username</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 1.Right - at firefox - the words are showed separated :-(  Please see the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ywsY/11/show/ 
2.That's exactly what I want to avoid ;-)